# Ubuntu on Hyper-V and VHDX

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, lvm, ext4, vhdx

I have a setup where I will run a Ubuntu Server on two VHDX disks. System 50GB and Data 4TB. They are located on a mirrored Storage Spaces Pool and are dynamic expanded.

During the Ubuntu installation the system disk got created on first VHDX as a EXT4 on a LVM pool.

My question is if its a good idea to use LVM on linux, or just simpel EXT4 on system and / or data-disk. Just a “mkfs”, file system creation of the Data-disk to EXT4 result in a 60GB expanded VHDX-file.

“mkfs -t ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=1 /dev/sdb1”

I created the machine before I read about the “VHDX Block Sizes”. So maybe thats a reason… http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/understanding-working-vhdx-files/

What are your thoughts? Regards, Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LVM gives you flexibility, storage snapshots and simplified volume expandability. In the case of generic Linux server on top of the "regular" storage, I would always recommend going with LVM, it makes the storage management much easier.

In your case, LVM won't really give you any significant benefits since VM is already sitting on top of redundant Storage Spaces with an ability to expand virtual disks and perform snapshots.

To sum up, choose one you are more comfortable with.

P.S.:I would use LVM myself anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather do ZoL instead of LVM + Ext3/4.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS